# Isolating letters in a string and converting them to a list

Tags: python, string, list, collections, converters

I want to be able to isolate the letters in a string from an input and return them as a collection containing 4 separate lower case characters.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    original = input(str("Enter a 4-letter word: "))

    letters = isolate_letters(original)

def isolate_letters(original):
    letters = list(original.items())

    return letters
main()
```

Comment: Can you show an example input and expected output? A string is already an iterable sequence, it is likely superfluous to make a list depending on what you want to do with the list.

Comment: string don't have `items()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "1234"
>>> list(s)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the first 4 lowercase characters:

```
letters = [c for c in original.lower() if c.isalpha()][:5]
```

- [str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)
- [str.lower](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

First you convert the string to lowercase (`lower()`), then pick out all the alphabet characters from the string (`isalpha()`) and finally slice off the first 4 (`[:5]`)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to filter for the ascii letters. If not, a python string is iterable, so for most practical applications a string behaves just like a list - try just using the string as if it was a list.

If you want all letters:

```
>>> import string
>>> original = "foo, bar, 2014"
>>> letters = [c for c in original if c in string.ascii_letters]
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

If you want them without repetitions:

```
>>> unique_letters = set(letters)
>>> unique_letters
{'a', 'b', 'f', 'o', 'r'}
```

[update]

> Thanks a lot! im new to python is there any chance you could explaiin how this works please?

Well, string.ascii_letters contains:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

We are using Python list comprehensions, a syntax based on the [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) in math:

```
[item for item in some_list if condition]
```

It is almost plain english: return a list of items in some_list if condition is true. In our case, we are testing if the character is an ascii letter using the `in` operator.

The `set` object in Python is an unordered list that ensure there is no repeated items.

Comment: Thanks a lot! im new to python is there any chance you could explaiin how this works please?